# Using navigator.plugins to determine Java version

Tags: java, javascript, version

The following javascript code will inform all your browser's enabled plugins (yeah, I know it doesn't work on IE, but for IE there's always deployJava):

```js
if ((navigator.plugins) && (navigator.plugins.length)) {

  for (var bb = 0, l = navigator.plugins.length; bb < l; bb++) {

    var vv = navigator.plugins[bb].name + "<br>"; 

    document.write(vv);

  }

}
```

I have Java 6.22 installed so the relevant line written to the page is this:

**Java(TM) Platform SE 6 U22**

My question is: how can I complement the above code so that it returns the major version (6) and update (22) found in my (or anyone's) browser?

I think the best way is to work with regular expression, but I am not good with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest (read: hackiest) solution would be something like this:

```
var plugin_name = navigator.plugins[bb].name
if (plugin_name.toLowerCase().indexOf("java") != -1) {
    var parts = plugin_name.split(" ").reverse();
    // if the plugin has an update
    if(plugin_name.match(/U[0-9]+/)) {
        // grab the end of the plugin name and remove non numeric chars
        var update = parts[0].replace(/[^0-9]/, "");
        // grab the major version and remove non numeric chars
        var major = parts[1].replace(/[^0-9]/, "");
        // print the major number and update number
        console.log(major);
        console.log(update);
    } else {
        var update = "0";
        // grab the major version and remove non numeric chars
        var major = parts[0].replace(/[^0-9]/, "");
        // print the major number and update number
        console.log(major);
        console.log(update);
    }  
}
```

You can then throw this code in your loop through the plugins and replace the `console.log` with whatever logic is appropriate given a major and update number.

Comment: It worked like a charm... with one exception.    

I installed Java 7 (without any update) and the plugin name is:    

**Java(TM) Platform SE 7**    

The result? Your code printed **E.7**    
This shortcoming probably affects Java 8 (without update, i.e. the first version). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @JohnD. check my update. we check whether an update is present; and if not, we print 0 as the update number.

Comment: thank you. I figured it out already but your code is also working.